# Hidden field Data is is not inserting in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to send 2 dates in MySQL table. Using following codes-

```
<table width="1050px"style="border:thin #00F solid"><tr><td>
<?php
$academic_info = getarrayassoc("SELECT * FROM `es_finance_master` ORDER BY `es_finance_masterid` DESC LIMIT 0,1");
$dfrom_acad = strtotime($academic_info['fi_ac_startdate']);
$dto_acad   = strtotime($academic_info['fi_ac_enddate']);
?>
<form  name="form" id="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="1029" cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="0" >
<tr>
<td height="25" colspan="5" class="bgcolor_02">Registration Form <span style="margin-left:500px;">Registration for <?php echo date('Y',$dfrom_acad). " - " . date('Y',$dto_acad) ?> Academic Year</span>
<input type="hidden" name="from_acad" value="<?php $academic_info['fi_ac_startdate']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="to_acad" value="<?php $academic_info['fi_ac_enddate']; ?>">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Reg. No. :</td>
<td width="330" ><input type="text" name="reg_no" id="reg_no" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['reg_no'])){echo $_POST['reg_no'];} ?>" onblur="reg_check()" />      <div id="reg_err"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

By the above code I can see the Years on top: But hidden fields data are not going to MySQL by using this code

```
$q2="insert into es_enquiry(eq_from_aca,eq_to_aca,eq_regno) values('".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['from_acad']))."','".date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['to_acad']))."','".$_POST['reg_no']."')";
```

Where is my mistake

Comment: Sidenote: Well for one thing, inserting directly from POST is not a good idea. And if by chance you're using `mysql_*`, that's another mistake.

Comment: You also need to echo your (hidden) inputs `<?php echo $academic_info['fi_ac_startdate']; ?>` and `<?php echo $academic_info['fi_ac_enddate']; ?>` even though they are hidden, they still need to be echo'ed. Which is probably the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Values of your hidden outputs are nothing cause you aren't using `echo`.

Try this:

```
value="<?php echo $academic_info['fi_ac_startdate']; ?>"
value="<?php echo $academic_info['fi_ac_enddate']; ?>"
```

Comment: I tried your way but my custom error message saying it is blank. `if(isset($_POST['from_acad']) && $_POST['to_acad']) { $errormessage[33] = "Blank Academic Year";}`

Answer (score 0):

I got my mistake why this code

```
if(isset($_POST['from_acad']) && $_POST['to_acad']) 
{ $errormessage[33] = "Blank Academic Year";}
```

is showing Error a silly mistake I left ! in isset

```
if(!isset($_POST['from_acad']) && $_POST['to_acad'])
{ $errormessage[33] = "Blank Academic Year";}
```

but I also like to thank all commentator for support.