# insert user id into form db submission php

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I post this question as a continuation of previous as it may have not been clear.

I have a login in system (session) running just fine - I want to capture the userID and insert the id into a form submission

```
<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>
```

I can get the id and display it just fine anywhere on the page - but can't insert the id into a hidden form field - looking for pointers as to how to do this.

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10"><input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" 
value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userID'];?>" /></div>

session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_home = new USER();

if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
{
    $user_home->redirect('login.php');
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
$stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;
?>
```

Comment: try like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638376/hidden-field-data-is-is-not-inserting-in-mysql

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Will you show your hidden field code

Comment: If you are getting your id in `<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>` then use `<input type="hidden" name="userId" id="userId" 
value="<?php echo $row['userID']; ?>" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`session_start();` should be called first before any HTML tags or even a space.

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  require_once 'class.user.php';
  $user_home = new USER();
  if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
    {
        $user_home->redirect('login.php');
    }

  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
  $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
```

And then you can use that session value anywhere through the website where `session_start()` is called.

In your case `insert.php` would look like:

```
<?php
session_start();

$server = "localhost"; 
$user = ""; $pass = ""; 
$dbname = ""; 
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname); 

if($conn->connect_error){ die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error); } 

$userID = $_SESSION['userId']; // Just use session value and no escaping required
$b_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_name']); 
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']); 
$b_area = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_area']); 
$tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tel']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO brands (userID, b_name, name, email, b_area, tel) VALUES ('$userID', '$b_name', '$name', '$email', '$b_area', '$tel')";
```

Comment: i kind of get the sessions - but my issue is that we already have code (sessions) for login at the top of the page - do I add another block of code to open another session? thanks for the reply, by the way.

Comment: @Brian What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: again thanks for your time - in simple terms .... we have a login system as you can see - that uses sessions. a logged in user has an id eg 6. 

the user can submit data - stored in db - I want to 'capture' the user id and include it in a hidden field which is sent to db - thus we know who the data belongs to and can call this data via SQL (select where userID = 6)

Comment: @Brian It would be great if you could add more code(HTML form and other PHP related code)

Comment: <?php 
  session_start();
  require_once 'class.user.php';
  $user_home = new USER();
  if(!$user_home->is_logged_in())
    {
        $user_home->redirect('login.php');
    }

  $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userID=:uid");
  $stmt->execute(array(":uid"=>$_SESSION['userSession']));
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $_SESSION['userId'] = $userId;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mediata Self-Serve</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

Comment: <div class="col-xs-12">
       <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userId'];?>"/>
         </div>
        </div>        
        <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-sm-10">

Comment: <?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "";
$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);
if($conn->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}
$userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userID']);
$b_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_name']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$b_area = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_area']);
$tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tel']);

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO brands (userID, b_name, name, email, b_area, tel) VALUES ('$userID', '$b_name', '$name', '$email', '$b_area', '$tel')";

Comment: does this help?

Comment: @Brian Just use `$_SESSION['userId']` directly into the SQL. Sessions are available to any page with `session_start();`. There are no security issues in doing this since the session values are stored on the server-side and user can not set this value.

Comment: not bother with the hidden field you mean - just direct in the insert.php that contains the SQL -

Comment: $userID = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['userID']);
$b_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_name']);
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$b_area = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['b_area']);
$tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tel']);

 
$sql = "INSERT INTO brands (userID, b_name, name, email, b_area, tel) VALUES ('$userID', '$b_name', '$name', '$email', '$b_area', '$tel')";

Comment: where would that go in this set ? never done that before

Comment: @Brian I updated my answer. Take a look how insert.php would look like

Comment: sad to say - No - same issue - all other fields transfer to the db - but not the user id - I ran a direct SQL in MyAdmin and a value inserted just fine ....

so scratching my head ....

Comment: @Brian In `insert.php`, try `print_r($_SESSION)` and paste the results here

Comment: not sure what should happen - added the line - called insert directly - it added a record to the db but just 0

Comment: Array ( [userSession] => 6 [userID] => [userId] => )

is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @Brian There you go. In `insert.php` change `$userID` to `$userID = $_SESSION['userSession'];`

Comment: and that seems to have solved the issue ,,,,,, brilliant a million thanks - I can now sit back and watch the Brit GP

Comment: Yep. Session value of userId was empty

Comment: Yep :). We just skipped the entire input part

Answer (score 0):

Put session_start() before trying to access your session variables. Like this :

```
if ( !session_id() )
{
    session_start();
}
```